# while statement-to repeat it again

Tags: c#, do-while

Everything is allright except the while statement.If you guys can help me that would be great.When the user write "Y" to do it again, he see: max value is: bla bla.

the user has to give a new positive number  instead of to see the maximum value over and over again.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please give a positieve number. if you enter a negatieve number its not going to work");


                int invoer = 0, max = 0;
                string repeat = "";


                do
                {

                    for (int i = 1; invoer >= 0; i++)
                    {

                        Console.Write(i + "> ");
                        invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (max < invoer)
                        {
                            max = invoer;
                        }
                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("Maximum value is: " + max);


                    Console.WriteLine("do you want to try again? y/n: ");
                    repeat = Console.ReadLine();

                } while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");
```

Comment: Okay, you corrected the mistake. Is the problem solved?

Comment: nope. problem is not solved. i just forgot to translate it to english

Comment: Ah, okay. Set max=0 and invoer=0 right before the for loop, otherwise they still have the values from the previous run.

Comment: you are great.the problem is solved. but can u explain it why?

Comment: max and invoer are variables, they store values. If they would forget values, they would be pretty useless, right?

Comment: allright. just one more question. Is it possible to solve this problem with an another way?

Comment: A variable exists only in the scope in which it is declared, and in any nested scopes. A scope is defined for example by the curly braces { }.

Comment: What do you mean with "another way"? It is a pretty fuzzy question you asked there.

Comment: I mean Is this the only way to do it.

Comment: No it is not the only way. As the saying goes, "there's more than one way to skin a cat". But that would not really be a discussion, but rather telling each other our opinions, preferences, styles, half wisdoms, and our favourite kind of pizza we like to eat while coding...

Comment: Got it. I have an another question for you. For example. If the user write -1 as the first number, the program can not find the maximumum value.right. So the result will 0. then we have to write an another code. for example if the first number less then 0 then the user has to see "wrong number or something like that"

Comment: Your idea about handling invalid values makes sense. Was that the implied question? ;)

Comment: i am still here! selectdistinct. not to be prejudiced

Comment: @elgonzo yeah that was a question actually. thanks by the way for your patience.

Comment: @user2880279 Sorry! I still think that you should get elgonzo to answer the question so you can accept it, or answer the question yourself. Other people may find this usefull in the future, ya know?

Comment: he didn't write it as an answer. you are the one who didn't solved the problem but write it down  just like you solved it. anyway if somebody will get the same problem in the future, they can see the answer now (thanks to you) and + a weird guy who is hanging out around here and checking everything is allright or not! and make prejudiced comments like : "too many duff accounts created by people who only care about their own answer rather than other people who may read this in the future."

Comment: I didnt read all the comments (my mistake), I saw there was no accepted answer so had a go at answering it. After I had done that I realised that this question had been resolved (in the comments section) even though on the face of it it was still flagged as unaswered, which was annoying as I spent time trying to help you. Sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im guessing at what this is supposed to be doing....

```
   {

                //Console.WriteLine("Please give a positive number. if you enter a negative number its not going to work");

                int invoer;
                int max;
                string repeat;



                do
                {
                    //they have given a negative number and wish to try again
                    Console.WriteLine("Please give a positive number.\nIf you enter a negative number its not going to work");

                    invoer = 0;
                    max = 0;
                    repeat = "";

                    for (int i = 1; invoer >= 0; i++)
                    {

                        Console.Write(i + "> ");
                        invoer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                        if (max < invoer)
                        {
                            max = invoer;
                        }
                    }


                    Console.WriteLine("Maximum value is: " + max);


                    Console.WriteLine("do you want to try again? y/n: ");
                    repeat = Console.ReadLine();

                } while (repeat == "y" || repeat == "Y");


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you need to move your deceleration of invover and max into your do loop.